# jQuery UI sortable not working with ajax html data

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

i am new to jquery, and for some reason my sortable list is not working with `sortable`

i am just practising

my code

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable();

$.ajax({
      url: baseUrl+'/loadFields/,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(data)
      {
        $('#fields').html(data);
      }
    });
```

the div where the data is loaded

```
<div id="fields"></div>
```

and the html file, where the list is contained

```
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

And when i try to drag nothing happens, if i dont load the html with ajax and do it like this

```
<div id="fields">
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

it works fine

Could please someone tell me how to use it with the ajax data?

Comment: Dynamic element creation doesn't matter when it comes to `sortable` lists as long as you identify the lists properly and handle all the event's properties with care.  See my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="fields">
<ul class="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 5</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 6</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.ui-icon {float:left;margin-right:8px;}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".sortable").sortable("refresh"); // add this line to "re-load" the sortable list after populating
$(".sortable").ready(function() {
  $( ".sortable" ).sortable(
      {
          handle: '.ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s',
          items: 'li',
          containment: '#fields',
          forceHelperSize: true,
          forcePlaceHolderSize: true,
          start: function(e, ui) {
              ui.item.addClass('ui-state-highlight');
          },
          stop: function(e, ui) {
              ui.item.removeClass('ui-state-highlight').effect('highlight',{},2000);;
          },
          update: function() {
              $('.sortable').sortable('refreshPositions');
          }
      }
  );
});
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/kULud/)

Comment: you totally got me wrong, it does not work with your code either, because im loading my data with AJAX, if i dont load it with ajax it works but iwth AJAX load it does not

Comment: @user1512390 Are you sure? I dynamically populate all of my sortable lists and they all seem to work fine. Maybe you should check to see if the list is DOMReady before you try using the `.sortable()` method.

Comment: tried that too, does not work, that is why i am totally cluless

Comment: thanks for you patienc still the same thing, checked something, when i view my source the ajax data content is visible in the dom, only shows in firebug, could that be the problem?

Comment: Are you primarily using FF or Chrome? Do Firebug / DevTools both give you a `200 OK` that the data is being returned properly? Does my fiddle work in your browser? Could you kindly post the AJAX call that populates `.sortable()`?

Comment: thanks for you help but i think you dont understand me, i will go and do research somewhere else, gave you a vote up for your time, and patience, thank you for that

Comment: Same problem here. What's your baseURL? Perhaps if you're using an absolute URL you need to load JQ libraries again whereas with a relative URL you don't?